# Cannot implicitly convert type of dynamic linq-to-sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I created one method in my model :

```
public IList<Test> GetData(int IDCus){

var list = from j in Context.Test
join y in this.Context.Test1 on j.ID equals y.ID
where j.ID == IDCus
select new {
    Tnum = j.Ynum,
    Level = y.Level
};
    return list.ToList();
}
```

When I just using `select` without `new`, it work normally. But when I tried to used `select new` in my query, it error : Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IList<ITEX.Models.Test>`.

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: Error speaks itself, You are returning IList<Test>, but when you do new with select, you are creating an anonymous type which is not "Test"

Comment: Thank. but could you tell me, why you said, I am creating anonymous type with is not Test? Because, j.Ynum is the field that I take from table "Test" and y.Level take from table Test1.

Comment: When you use "select" as above, you are projecting your result to a new "Type" which was anonymously created by the compiler(feature of C# 3.0). To specify the Type to what you are willing to return, you have to use - select new Test() {Tnum = j.Ynum, Level = y.Level}, this will ensure you are returning Test object instead of creating a new anonymous type.

Comment: Oh thanks Flowerking, But I have one problem while I create `Tnum`, It error : the `Test` does not contain the definition of `Tnum`.

Comment: sorry my Mistake, Your query shows you are taking Level from Test1 and Ynum from Test, so how can you project it to "Test" object? why don't you create a new class with properties Tnum, Level and return that in your Ilist<newType> instead of going for "Test"

Comment: But I really have no idea, what type should I put in here?

Comment: Just create a class with two public properties with names Tnum and Level, Make sure they are of same type that of j.Ynum, y.Level. i.e. like int/string  etc. Now use IList<YourNewClass>. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `Ynum` and `Level` are int you first have to verify that the class `Test` looks like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Tnum { get; set; }
    public int Level {get;set;}
}
```

And then the query should look something like this:

```
public IList<Test> GetData(int IDCus)
{
    var list = (
                from j in Context.Test
                join y in this.Context.Test1 
                    on j.ID equals y.ID
                where 
                    j.ID == IDCus
                select new Test()
                    {
                        Tnum = j.Ynum,
                        Level = y.Level
                    }
            );
    return list.ToList();
}
```

If you are using `Test` somewhere else you might have to create a new class for this call, we can call it `Test2`. Then the class should look like this:

```
public class Test2
{
    public int Tnum { get; set; }
    public int Level {get;set;}
}
```

And the function for getting the information should look like this:

```
public IList<Test2> GetData(int IDCus)
{
    var list = (
                from j in Context.Test
                join y in this.Context.Test1 
                    on j.ID equals y.ID
                where 
                    j.ID == IDCus
                select new Test2()
                    {
                        Tnum = j.Ynum,
                        Level = y.Level
                    }
            );
    return list.ToList();
}
```

I hope this will help